# Slow boot caused by DMA Write / caused by PTE Write access is not set

Tags: 20.04

I experience a slow boot of Ubuntu 20.04, it takes about 2 min. I have pinpointed the issue. However, I don't understand the error. There are several issues. However, some search on the internet doesn't give a solution or a better understanding of the issue.

The system (notebook):

- TOXIC AURIX 17" MK-III from BTO
- Intel® Core i9-10900K Processor
- OS Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Base board information: Notebook product name X170KM-G
- year of build: august 2021
- Bios Vendor os INSYDE Corp. Version 1.07.04TNB (release 01/11/2020)
- NVIDIA®GeForce®RTX 3080
- NVIDIA-SMI 470.63.01 / CUDA Version 11.4

During boot I obtain the following:

```
DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set

DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set

DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set
```

The output of `journalctl -p 3 -xb` gives:

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS

mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee0000000040110a

mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef20300 MISC 3880000086 

mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:a0655 TIME 1630579052 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode ec

tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead

DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set

DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set

DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set

DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set

thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: failed to send driver ready to ICM
```

Extra step, however no solution:

In /etc/default/grub I add

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off"
```

and perform `sudo update-grub` However it doesn't solve the issue.

Update to Ubuntu 21.04 doesn't solve the issue. I reinstall Ubuntu 20.04. I am running Lambda Stack, is currently supported for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, and 16.04 LTS

Output `lspci -tv`:

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Device 9b33
           +-01.0-[01]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation Device 24dc
           |            \-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation Device 228b
           +-08.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Device 43ed
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Device 43ef
           +-14.3  Intel Corporation Device 43f0
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation Device 43e8
           +-15.1  Intel Corporation Device 43e9
           +-15.2  Intel Corporation Device 43ea
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Device 43e0
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Device 43d2
           +-19.0  Intel Corporation Device 43ad
           +-19.2  Intel Corporation Device 43a7
           +-1b.0-[02]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
           +-1c.0-[03-6b]----00.0-[04-6a]--+-00.0-[05]----00.0  Intel Corporation Device 1137
           |                               +-01.0-[06-37]--
           |                               +-02.0-[38]----00.0  Intel Corporation Device 1138
           |                               \-03.0-[39-6a]--
           +-1d.0-[6c]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
           +-1d.5-[6d]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 3000
           +-1d.6-[6e]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Device 4385
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Device f0c8
           +-1f.4  Intel Corporation Device 43a3
           \-1f.5  Intel Corporation Device 43a4
```

- memtest: pass
- "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset" -> no success, still a long reboot time. The output of `journalctl -p 3 -xb` gives still the above errors. I also modify the /etc/default/grub and perform `sudo update-grub`. No success.
- `sudo lshw -c storage -c disk` provides following output:

```
*-sata                    
       description: SATA controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 17
       bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
       version: 11
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:a2590000-a2591fff memory:a2594000-a25940ff ioport:5040(size=8) ioport:5048(size=4) ioport:5020(size=32) memory:a2593000-a25937ff
  *-storage
       description: Non-Volatile memory controller
       product: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
       vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:a2400000-a2403fff
     *-nvme0
          description: NVMe device
          product: Samsung SSD 980 1TB
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/nvme0
          version: 1B4QFXO7
          serial: S649NF0R594587R
          configuration: nqn=nqn.1994-11.com.samsung:nvme:980M.2:S649NF0R594587R state=live
        *-namespace
             description: NVMe namespace
             physical id: 1
             logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: guid=c1d7d756-6025-4936-ae78-8096dd1aa5b1 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
*-storage
       description: Non-Volatile memory controller
       product: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
       vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:6c:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:a2300000-a2303fff
     *-nvme1
          description: NVMe device
          product: Samsung SSD 980 1TB
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/nvme1
          version: 1B4QFXO7
          serial: S649NF1R501393P
          configuration: nqn=nqn.1994-11.com.samsung:nvme:980M.2:S649NF1R501393P state=live
        *-namespace
             description: NVMe namespace
             physical id: 1
             logical name: /dev/nvme1n1
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=b7d3e066
```

- `sudo dmidecode -t 8` gives:

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3 present.
# SMBIOS implementations newer than version 3.2.0 are not
# fully supported by this version of dmidecode.

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_HDMI1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: <BAD INDEX>
    External Connector Type: Other
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_CRT1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: CRT
    External Connector Type: Other
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_DP2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: DP2
    External Connector Type: Other
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_AUDIO2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Headphone
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_INTMIC1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: MIC In
    External Connector Type: Other
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_USB3_1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB Port1
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_USB3_2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB Port2
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_USB3_3
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB Port3
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_TYPEC1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB Port1
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_RJ_1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Giga Lan
    External Connector Type: RJ-45
    Port Type: Network Port

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J_CARD-REV1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Card Reader
    External Connector Type: Other
    Port Type: Other
```

---

It seems there is no Thunderbolt support, i.e. Security Level could not be determined.

In the BIOS I disable the Discrete Thunderbolt Support. I still get no Thunderbolt support (Security Level could not be determined). However, the system boots in less than 30 secs (in the past it takes 120 secs) and I don't get DMAR errors and also no thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: failed to send driver ready to ICM message.

It saims Thunderbolt is the source of the issue.

---

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard. What version Nvidia driver? Try adding kernel parameter "intel_iommu=igfx_off" to /etc/default/grub kernel line and then updating grub and see if that helps.

Comment: You forgot to give me some information...

Comment: Sorry.   sudo dmidecode -s bios-version gives 1.07.04TNB, Notebook product name is X170KM-G (year aug 2021) (TOXIC AURIX 17" MK-III form BTO), Bios Vendor INSYDE Corp., Nvidia driver is 470.63.01. I add  "intel_iommu=igfx_off" to /etc/default/grub, however, it doesn't work.

Comment: I **assume** that the brand name is Clevo?? The Clevo web site doesn't easily give up BIOS information. You'll have to research this on your own, and check for a newer BIOS. Exactly where did you add the iommu string in /etc/default/grub?

Comment: add the end of the file.

Comment: That's not the kernel line. Remove that edit. Find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off", save the file, then do `sudo update-grub`, reboot and check for remaining problem.

Comment: Create a Ubuntu Live USB 21.04 and see if that boots without error.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off" + sudo update-grub doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Remove the edit, update grub, and try the 21.04 USB. Also research the BIOS update. Report back.

Comment: 21.04 doesn't solve the issue. I need to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 because I run Lambda Stack which is currently only for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I check if I can update the Bios.

Comment: @heynnema Bios Version 1.07.04TNB is the latest version. I also upgrade to 21.04 without success. I had to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 because I use Lambda Stack, which is currently only available in 20.04. Any suggestions on how to proceed are welcome.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lspci -tv`. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema memtest pass, I edit the question and add output `lspci -tv`.

Comment: For testing purposes, try this temporary mod. At the GRUB menu, select the desired boot item, hit the "e" key to enter edit mode. Find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then control-x or F10 to continue booting. See if there's any change.

Comment: Tell me all devices connected to USB, SATA, or HDMI.

Comment: @heynnema I edit my question with extra info.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was having trouble identifying "device [05:00.0]", but in reading closer, I think I figured it out. I see "thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0"... do you have any thunderbolt devices connected? Also, check your Samsung SSD firmware by downloading Samsung Magician at https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/.

Comment: The extra info didn't clarify what actual DP, HDMI, and USB devices you have connected. Please describe.

Comment: @heynnema I have no external devices connected. Concerning, the Samsung SSD firmware. Inside the laptop, there are two 1TB Samsung 980 NVME PCI-e 3.0 x4, M.2. Both are working perfectly. I don't understand why I need to update the Firmware.

Comment: @heynnema In meantime I checked SDD firmware so far I see no firmware update for the Samsung 980.

Comment: @heynnema It seems there is no Thunderbolt support, i.e. Security Level could not be determined. What I have done, in the bios, I disable the Discrete Thunderbolt Support. I still get no Thunderbolt support (Security Level could not be determined), however, the system boots in less than 30 secs (in the past it takes 120 secs) and I don't get DMAR and no thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: failed to send driver ready to ICM message. It saims Thunderbolt is the source of the issue.

Comment: Did you check both Samsung SSD's? You may need Ubuntu 21.04 for Thunderbolt support. I'll put together a quick answer for you. Maybe you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I check both SSD's so far I see no firmware update. I will update to 21.04 the moment Lambda Stack Supports 21.04. Thanks for the support!

Comment: You can boot to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode (with Thunderbolt enabled) and check the boot times (understanding that it'll be a little slow anyway due to USB drives) and error messages. It won't disturb your current installation.

Comment: I try Ubuntu 21.04, however no success. Currently, I don' need Thunderbolt, it is not critical.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I was having trouble identifying "device [05:00.0]", but in reading closer, I think I figured it out. I see "thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0"... do you have any thunderbolt devices connected?*

```
DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2

DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [05:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 6d95f000 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set

thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: failed to send driver ready to ICM
```

Ubuntu 20.04. Turned off Thunderbolt support in the BIOS, and now the laptop boots in less than 30 seconds, instead of 2 minutes with lots of error messages.

Suspect that with such new hardware, you'll need to update to Ubuntu 21.04 for full support.